# Recreate html page from array (2.0)

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, tags

Good morning everyone,
Yesterday I asked a question to resolve this problem but array was flawed.
Now the array seems fixed but I'm having troubles to create the page.
So, this is the fixed array

```
'tag' => array(
    'tagName' => 'section',
    'tagAttributes' => array(
        'class' => 'main full',
    ),
    'tagContents' => array(
        'tag' => array(
            'tagName' => 'img',
            'tagAttributes' => array(
                'class' => 'logo',
                'src' => 'assets/images/logo-480x176.png'
            )
        ),
        'tag_1' => array(
            'tagName' => 'div',
            'tagAttributes' => array(
                'class' => 'cover sfondo'
            ),
            'tagContents' => array(
                'tag' => array(
                    'tagName' => 'img',
                    'tagAttributes' => array(
                        'class' => 'cover-image',
                        'src' => 'assets/images/cover-img-header.png'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'tag_2' => array(
        'tagName' => 'div',
        'tagAttributes' => array(
            'class' => 'cover-mob sfondo-mob'
        ),
        'tagContents' => array(
            'tag' => array(
                'tagName' => 'img',
                'tagAttributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'cover-image-mob',
                    'src' => 'assets/images/cover-img-mobile.jpg'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'tag_3' => array(
        'tagName' => 'a',
        'tagAttributes' => array(
            'class' => 'button order light'
        ),
        'tagContents' => array(
            'tag' => array(
                'tagName' => 'div',
                'tagAttributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'data-min',
                ),
                'tagContents' => array(
                    'tag' => array(
                        'tagName' => 'div',
                        'tagAttributes' => array(
                            'class' => 'label-holder',
                        ),
                        'tagContents' => array(
                            'tag' => array(
                                'tagName' => 'img',
                                'tagAttrbiutes' => array(
                                    'src' => 'assets/images/sfondo-cta.jpg'
                                )
                            ),
                            'tag_1' => array(
                                'tagName' => 'p',
                                'tagAttributes' => array(
                                    'class' => 'label',
                                ),
                                'tagContents' => array(
                                    'strong' => 'text'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    'tag_1' => array(
                        'tagName' => 'div',
                        'tagAttributes' => array(
                            'class' => 'price-holder'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'tag_1' => array(
            'tagName' => 'div',
            'tagAttributes' => array(
                'class' => 'cta'
            ),
            'tagContents' => array(
                'tag' => array(
                    'tagName' => 'p',
                    'tagAttributes' => array(
                        'class' => 'main-title'
                    ),
                    'tagContents' => array(
                        'tag' => array(
                            'tagName' => 'a',
                            'tagAttributes' => array(
                                'strong' => 'text'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'tag_2' => array(
            'tagName' => 'img',
            'tagAttributes' => array(
                'class' => 'main-title',
                'src' => 'assets/images/extra_1.png'
            )
        )
    )
),
'tag_1' => array(
    'tagName' => 'section',
    'tagAttributes' => array(
        'class' => 'gallery',
        'id' => 'video'
    ),
    'tagContents' => array(
        'tag' => array(
            'tagName' => 'p',
            'tagAttributes' => array(
                'class' => 'title video-title',
            ),
            'tagContents' => array(
                'tag' => array(
                    'tagName' => 'span',
                    'tagAttributes' => array(
                        'strong' => 'text'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'tag_1' => array(
            'tagName' => 'div',
            'tagAttributes' => array(
                'class' => 'container',
            ),
            'tagContents' => array(
                'tag' => array(
                    'tagName' => 'div',
                    'tagAttributes' => array(
                        'class' => 'arrow-container prev',
                    ),
                    'tagContents' => array(
                        'tag' => array(
                            'tagName' => 'img',
                            'tagAttributes' => array(
                                'class' => 'arrow',
                                'src' => 'assets/images/freccia-sx_1.png'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'tag_2' => array(
            'tagName' => 'div',
            'tagAttributes' => array(
                'class' => 'arrow-container next',
            ),
            'tagContents' => array(
                'tag' => array(
                    'tagName' => 'img',
                    'tagAttributes' => array(
                        'class' => 'arrow',
                        'src' => 'assets/images/freccia-dx_1.png'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'tag_3' => array(
            'tagName' => 'div',
            'tagAttributes' => array(
                'class' => 'gallery-holder'
            ),
            'tagContents' => array(
                'tag' => array(
                    'tagName' => 'div',
                    'tagAttributes' => array(
                        'class' => 'internal single'
                    ),
                    'tagContents' => array(
                        'tag' => array(
                            'tagName' => 'div',
                            'tagAttributes' => array(
                                'class' => 'gallery-item video',
                            ),
                            'tagContents' => array(
                                'tag' => array(
                                    'tagName' => 'div',
                                    'tagAttributes' => array(
                                        'class' => 'wrapper video-wrapper'
                                    ),
                                    'tagContents' => array(
                                        'tag' => array(
                                            'tagName' => 'img',
                                            'tagAttributes' => array(
                                                'class' => 'play-vid pointer thumb',
                                                'src' => 'assets/images/img-spot-tv.png'
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        'tag_1' => array(
                                            'tagName' => 'img',
                                            'tagAttributes' => array(
                                                'class' => 'play-icon hover',
                                                'src' => 'assets/images/play.png'
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
```

And this is how I tried to create html page

```
foreach ($MiniSiteStructureArray as $section => $sectionStructure) {

    $html = '<' . $sectionStructure['tagName'] . '';
    foreach ($sectionStructure['tagAttributes'] as $name => $value) {
        $html .= " $name='" . $value . "'>";
    }
    foreach ($sectionStructure['tagContents'] as $contents) {
        foreach ($contents['tagAttributes'] as $name => $value) {
            $html .= '<' . $contents['tagName'] . ' ' . $name . '="' . $value . '">';
        }
        if (isset($contents['tagContents'])) {
            $html .= findAllContents($contents['tagContents'], $html);
        }
    }
}

function findAllContents($tagContents, $tmpHtml) {
    foreach ($tagContents as $tag => $tagValue) {
        if (isset($tagValue['tagAttributes'])) {
            foreach ($tagValue['tagAttributes'] as $tagKey => $value) {
                $tmpHtml = '<' . $tagValue['tagName'] . ' ' . $tagKey . '="' . $value . '"></' . $tagValue['tagName'] . '>';
            }
        }
    }
    return $tmpHtml;
}

echo $html;
```

But there are some issues.

Cycling 'tagAttributes' for example.

1) The code finds 'class' => 'logo' but later it finds 'src' => 'assets/...' and overwrite previous values.

2) same thing with $html

Edit_1 :

```
   foreach ($MiniSiteStructureArray as $section => $sectionStructure) {
    $html = '<' . $sectionStructure['tagName'] . '';
    foreach ($sectionStructure['tagAttributes'] as $name => $value) {
        $html .= " $name='" . $value . "'>";
    }
    foreach ($sectionStructure['tagContents'] as $contents) {
        $html .= '<' . $contents['tagName'];
        foreach ($contents['tagAttributes'] as $name => $value) {
            $html.=' '. $name . '="' . $value . '">';
        }
        if (isset($contents['tagContents'])) {
            $html .= findAllContents($contents['tagContents'], $html);
        }
    }
    $html .= '</'.$contents['tagName'].'>';   
}

function findAllContents($tagContents, $tmpHtml) {
    foreach ($tagContents as $tag => $tagValue) {
        $tmpHtml = '<' . $tagValue['tagName'];

        if (isset($tagValue['tagAttributes'])) {
            foreach ($tagValue['tagAttributes'] as $tagKey => $value) {
                $tmpHtml .= ' ' . $tagKey . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $tmpHtml .= '></' . $tagValue['tagName'] . '>';
    }
    return $tmpHtml;
}
```

Better, thanks.

Now remains the $html issue.
I'd been thinking to open a html tag like this `$html = <html><head></head><body>` at the beginning of the code and close html tag and body tag at the end but I tried and doesn't work.

Edit_2 :

Ok, it's done I think. I only add a this `$html = ''` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open your tag before `tagAttributes` foreach loop and close after it. There will be also problem if you don't add tagAttributes key to your array, so the tag itself will be omitted.

Example of modification your foreach loop for `findAllContents()`:

```
foreach ($tagContents as $tag => $tagValue) {
    $tmpHtml .= '<' . $tagValue['tagName']

    if (isset($tagValue['tagAttributes'])) {
        foreach ($tagValue['tagAttributes'] as $tagKey => $value) {
            $tmpHtml .= ' ' . $tagKey . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }

    $tmpHtml .= '></' . $tagValue['tagName'] . '>';
}
```